Choosing a durable 4 wire connection coming from the edge of a cylinder
I am making a set of electronic bagpipes, and i need to connect the PCB holding the optical sensors for the fingers to a synthesizer board through a cable of a couple of meters. For the moment i haven't used any connector at all. I have just cut a cable and soldered it on the PCB. But i am a little bit afraid of the durability of this solution on the long term. Even a connector would be subject to movements of the cable. (i thought of putting a USB-C receptacle, because of the small size and ease of finding such cables).
The cable comes out at a 90° angle, from a cylindrical shape of 25mm diameter.
I'd like something that would be easily repairable if something goes wrong. Do you have any better suggestions ?

Subjective questions like shopping and component selection is not accepted on this site, but I want to give the general statement of don't use USB-C, unless you implement proper USB. Please. I would look through the catalog of a distributor like digikey or mouser, and look for wire-to-board-connectors.

Relatively cheap, common and popular 50 years ago:

DIN connectors, 5-pin. Note that both shown are female versions.
A bit more pricey but more robust and easier to work with:

XLR 4-pole.
Both are available globally from all the usual suppliers.

Q: What's the definition of a gentleman?
A: Someone who can play the bagpipes - but doesn't.
